# String manipulation in pine?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How would I decompose start/end and hrs as well minutes from this?

```
sessionInput = input.session("0600-1700", "Session")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decomposite the input string into an array of strings using the str.split() function:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Session start/end', overlay=true)
sessionInput  = input.session("0600-1700", "Session")

var string[] sessionStartEnd = str.split(sessionInput, '-')

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, high, 'session start :' + array.get(sessionStartEnd, 0))
    label.new(bar_index, low, 'session end :' + array.get(sessionStartEnd, 1))
```

Comment: thanks mate. Since I need to decompose h and m as well, substring is more suitable in this case. however, I didnt knew about split either and can need it for something else - allowing me to declutter some functions. Thanks for sharing.